# Unknown function `corner' in for-loops

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, loops

I would like to draw this graph: each side of the regular pentagon is replaced by five circular dots.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\drawLineWithPoints}[2]{ 
  \foreach \i in {0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1} {
    \coordinate (point) at ($#1!\i!#2$);
    \draw (point) circle (2pt);
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum size=4cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5] (a) {};


\foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\i+1}
  \ifnum\j>5
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{1}
  \fi
  \drawLineWithPoints{(a.corner \i)}{(a.corner \j)}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But it shows me `! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function` corner' (in 'corner 0').`

If I give up the for-loop and write each `\drawLineWithPoints` statement one by one, it works fine.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum size=4cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5] (a) {};

\drawLineWithPoints{(a.corner 1)}{(a.corner 2)}
\drawLineWithPoints{(a.corner 2)}{(a.corner 3)}
\drawLineWithPoints{(a.corner 3)}{(a.corner 4)}
\drawLineWithPoints{(a.corner 4)}{(a.corner 5)}
\drawLineWithPoints{(a.corner 5)}{(a.corner 1)}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Why?

Comment: You're using `\i` twice. Use another loop variable inside `\drawLineWithPoints`. Or `\expanded{\noexpand\drawLineWithPoints{(a.corner \i)}{(a.corner \j)}}` but that's not really necessary.

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Can I set \i to be a local variable in the function drawLineWithPoints?

Comment: It is local but with TeX you can't access the same macro from another scope. You will need to use another variable or expand `\i` before it gets into your macro. (Or you place the circles via the `decorations.markings` library.)