# How to evenly substitute each side of a regular pentagon with five circles?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-decorations

This is an extension of  [the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699941/unknown-function-corner-in-for-loops). Thanks for the tips from the user
[Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel). I would like to evenly substitute each side of a regular pentagon with five circles.

I decided to use `decorations`, but I noticed that the circle replacements don't look quite even. Furthermore, I'd prefer it to happen automatically, without me having to manually adjust its `shape sep`. Ideally, I want all five corners of the regular pentagon to have circles substituted.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
      shape backgrounds,shape=circle,shape size=2mm}]
  \draw[thick, red, decorate, decoration={shape sep=0.75cm}] (90:2)--(162:2)--(234:2)--(306:2)--(378:2)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Below is the code I wrote myself to replace each line segment with five circles, which meets my requirements, but the code seems a bit cumbersome.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\drawLineWithPoints}[2]{ 
  \foreach \w in {0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1} {
    \coordinate (point) at ($#1!\w!#2$);
    \draw [red] (point) circle (2pt);
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum size=2cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5] (a) {};


\foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\i+1}
  \ifnum\j>5
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{1}
  \fi
  \drawLineWithPoints{(a.corner \i)}{(a.corner \j)}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edits:**  Using `decorations.markings`.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
  mydecoration/.style={
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.25 with {
        \fill (0,0) circle (2pt);
      }
    },
    postaction={decorate}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \angle in {90, 162, 234, 306, 378}{
  \path[thick, red, mydecoration](\angle:1)--({\angle+72}:1);
  
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `markings` decoration allows you to place one or more markings on a path.  One possible construction would be with `mark=between positions 0 and 1 step{.2} with {...}`.  You would get both extremities on each side.  Maybe `.2 and 1 step {.2}` would be nicer.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? It looks pretty good to me and not at all cumbersome. You could replace `\coordinate (point) at ($#1!\w!#2$);
    \draw [red] (point) circle (2pt);` with a single line `\draw [red] ($#1!\w!#2$) circle (2pt);` assuming you don't use `point` as a reference elsewhere.

Comment: @DanielN You could, but is there any advantage? You could also use, say, `evaluate` in the `\foreach` loop but, honestly, I don't see what the problem is meant to be with the current code.

Comment: @cft As mentioned in the main text, decorations for paths are already implemented in TikZ. So I feel that my implementation felt somewhat redundant. I have reworked it (by using `markings`)to achieve the desired result; see new edit.

Comment: @licheng As I say in my answer, it is partly a matter of taste. But there may be some objective reason to prefer doing it that way, for sure. Perhaps the code is more efficient, for example. Otherwise, whichever will make most sense to you in a year's time without consulting the docs is probably as good a basis for choosing as any. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I don't think there's anything wrong with the code you posted. It doesn't seem cumbersome to me. Nonetheless, you could streamline it slightly, if you wish.

There are different ways to do this and some of the differences are matters of personal preference.

In the code you posted, you don't really need the coordinate `(point)` as you could just say

```
         \draw [red] ($#1!\w!#2$) circle (2pt);
```

You could also reduce the `pgfmath` at the cost of making the set of values for your main loop a little uglier. Basically, the idea is to set `\j` directly and to use a `count` of the loops for `\i`.

```
  \foreach \j [count=\i] in {2,...,5,1}{
    \drawLineWithPoints{(a.corner \i)}{(a.corner \j)}
  }
```

Because we're not calculating anything, we can keep everything as integers without messing about with truncating the results of TeX arithmetic.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\drawLineWithPoints}[2]{ 
  \foreach \w in {0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1} {
    \draw [red] ($#1!\w!#2$) circle (2pt);
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[minimum size=2cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5] (a) {};
  
  \foreach \j [count=\i] in {2,...,5,1}{
    \drawLineWithPoints{(a.corner \i)}{(a.corner \j)}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 5 circles per side for pentagon]

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing wrong with your approach necessarily. My comment was merely a suggestion for you to consider other options. As always with TikZ, there are multiple approaches to any problem. The right choice will be dependent on the circumstances.

I like solutions that can be used in more than one case but are parametrized.

Here is a `polygon with red circles decorated = <sides> x <circles>` style that creates a regular polygon node with `<sides>` (via the `regular polygon` shape) that will be decorated with `<circles>` per side resulting in a total of `<sides>` × `<circles>` circles. In your case, this is `5 x 4`. The radius of the circles is determined by the value for `radius` which can be set alongside this style.

Another approach using the `polygon path = <phase>:<sides>:<radius>` style constructs a closed regular polygon with `<sides>` sides and a radius of `<radius>` where the first corner starts at `<phase>`°. (Note that the `minimum size` for the `regular polygon` shape specified the diameter.)
Since this style uses `to` we can hook into each side with the `every to` style that is used with `to with nodes = <nodes>` which will place `<nodes>` equally spaced on each `to` segment. This style does not specifiy the nodes at all, for this we can use `nodes` which I set up so that red circles will be placed again.

We could even use a different `to` path than `line to`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
  polygon path/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{% phase:n:radius
    insert path={({#1}:{#3}) foreach[parse=true] \i in {1, ..., #2-1}{
      to ({#1+\i*360/(#2)}:{#3})} to cycle}},
  to with nodes/.style={
    every to/.append style={
      edge node={node foreach \p in {1, ..., #1}[pos=\p/(#1)]{}}}},
  polygon with red circles decorated/.style args={#1x#2}{
    shape=regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides={#1},
    decorate,
    decoration={
      name=markings,
      mark=between positions 1/((#1)*(#2)) and 1 step 1/((#1)*(#2)) with {
        \draw[red] (0,0) circle[];}}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \node[minimum size=2cm, polygon with red circles decorated=5x4, radius=2pt] {};

\tikz
  \path[
    to with nodes=4,
    nodes={shape=circle, draw=red, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+4pt},
    polygon path={90:5:1}];

\tikz[row sep=5mm, column sep=5mm]
\matrix[
  radius=2pt,
  execute at empty cell={
    \node[
      minimum size=1cm,
      polygon with red circles decorated=
        \pgfmatrixcurrentrow+2 x \pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn] {};},
]{
  & & & & \\
  & & & & \\
  & & & & \\
  & & & & \\
};

\tikz[row sep=5mm, column sep=5mm]
\matrix[
  radius=2pt,
  cells={nodes={shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+2, draw, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+4pt}},
  execute at empty cell={
    \path[
      bend left,
      to with nodes=\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,
      polygon path={270-180/(\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow+2):
                    \the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow+2:.5}] {};},
]{
  & & & & \\
  & & & & \\
  & & & & \\
  & & & & \\
};
```

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This should definitely get the tick.